# exception after upgrading spring 3.2.0 to 4.3.3 with tomcat 8 , The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, servlets

```
I'm getting below exception after upgrading spring 3.2.0 to 4.3.3 with tomcat 8 , 
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest



**
```

> even i have javax.servlet-api dependency in pom.xml

**

```
<dependency>
<groupid>javax.servlet</groupid>
<artifactid>javax.servlet-api</artifactid>
<version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>


Please advise.
```

> Stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
>       at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:574)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:131)
>       at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at com.fmr.commons.cs203.servlet.CS203CoreServletFilter.doFilter(CS203CoreServletFilter.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:147)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: add `<scope>provided</scope>` to your `javax.servlet` dependency.

Comment: Hi Deinum, i have already tried <scope>provided</scope> but no luck,
i tried javax.servlet-api versions - 2.5, 3.0.1 and   3.1.0 , also did project clean build but still the same issues,

Comment: Also you should use the 3.0 version of the api tomcat 8 is a servlet 3.0 not a 3.1 provider. Also make sure you aren't including another version of that api. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to check your dependencies...